# How to force airplay for a specific app while keeping default audio device for everything else?

Tags: macos, audio, airplay

Is it possible to have Airplay enabled only for a *specific app*, while keeping the default built-in audio for the rest of the system?

Currently selecting an Airplay device via the global audio control (the  icon in the menu bar) will route *all the audio* via Airplay, and the workaround is to explicitly select the non-Airplay output such as `MacBook Speakers` or `Headphones` etc for all the apps that I do *not* want to use with Airplay (given that those apps have an option to select the output device, web browsers, for example, don't have such an option).

While some apps have a dropdown to select between 'Automatic' and an explicit audio device, none of them have the Airplay output listed as an option, apparently because at the OS level is not handled as an audio device.

Also, I've noticed that under *System Settings* > *Sound* there is an option *Play sound effects through <device>* so that system notification sounds won't use Airplay, but there doesn't seem to be a way to have an app use the 'sound effects' device rather than the automatic system default audio output.